# pyspark dataframe reference vs value

Tags: pyspark

I learn pyspark. I'm trying to build DataFrame from sql, for example

```
DF=spark.sql("with a as (select ....) select ...")
```

My sql is a little complex, so it's executed for 20 minutes.
I feel like DF is a refer to my SQL, it means when I execute DF.head(10) it takes 20 minuts, next step DF.count() takes also 20 minuts etc.
I'd like to have DataFrame like in pandas with value in RAM where DF.head(10), DF.count() take a few seconds.
The only way I can think of is to use "create table", for example:

```
xx=spark.sql("create table yyy as with a as (select ....) select ...")
DF=sqlContext.sql("select * from yyy")
```

It works but it looks strange to me.
What are the best practices to create DataFrame in pyspark from complex SQL ? I would like to skip the step with "create table".

Comment: Check `cache` in pyspark.  If you are doing action functions (count, head, show, etc) onto the same exact data, `cache` will help reduce the time from the 2nd action function.  https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-cache-and-persist-explained/

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to have DataFrame like in pandas with value in RAM where DF.head(10), DF.count() take a few seconds.

Pandas load your data into memory from the moment you **read** that data, that's why it's lightning-fast. But remember the data size you can load is limited to your computer's memory

> My sql is a little complex, so it's executed for 20 minutes. I feel like DF is a refer to my SQL, it means when I execute DF.head(10) it takes 20 minuts, next step DF.count() takes also 20 minuts etc.

Spark does **not** load the data when you read it. It only read data when there is an "action" like `cache` or `count` or `head`.

> The only way I can think of is to use "create table"

Yes, creating a table is also an action, where your query is executed entirely. Next time when you read it, it doesn't have to re-compute it. Tha alternative of creating table is caching, you can do something like this `DF.cache().count()`, spark will load entire data into memory and all other actions later will be much faster.